# Connecting a custom language to the Visual Studio C# debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am currently building a compiler which produces C# code. The goal would now be to create a debugger for my language in order to just forward data from the C# debugger.

I would like to show only local variables and to have support for breakpoints and such, but I would like to try and use a quick and dirty solution rather than build some large Visual Studio Extensibility library.

Is there some simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a problem with just stepping through the generated C# code?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way would be to integrate your compiler into VS and use it as a T4 Template code generator? Then you debug the C# code.

Comment: The generated C# is too ugly to step through it. Also, there is quite  a semantic jump between the host and target languages, so a proper debugger would really be useful...